# Adding Google Tag Manager from within Vue (after consent given)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to load Google Tag Manager after the user has given consent to do so. 
I know that there are many options out there, that can do it without having to use Vue, - but they're either [chunky](https://www.onetrust.com/), [massive](https://www.quantcast.com/) and/or [pricey](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/). And most of them are ugly too.

In order to implement Google Tag Manager, then a code-snippet has to be added in the `<head>` as well as 'first-thing-in-the-body'. And neither of which is inside the famous `#app`-vue-instance.

I'm using Vue with WordPress, so I don't/won't have Vue-Router or Vuex. It's an Nginx/Apache-server and the routing is controlled by WordPress.

Here is my code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.mixin( cookieMixins ); // loads getCookie and setCookie

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [
    cookieMixins
  ],
  data: {
    cookiesAccepted: false
  },
  mounted() {
    this.cookiesAccepted = ( this.getCookie( 'cookie_consent' ) === 'true' ); 
    this.addGtm();
  },
  methods: {
    acceptCookies() {
      this.setCookie( 'cookie_consent', 'true', 30 );
      this.cookiesAccepted = true;

      this.addGtm();
    },
    addGtm(){
      if( this.cookiesAccepted ){

        //
        // I want to add the 
        // Google Tag Manager tags (both the 
        // snippet for the head and the body here.
        //

      }
    }
  },
});
```

This is an attempt to become GDPR-compliant, - not loading any tracking codes before the user has given it's consent.

Is it true that I need to put this as a JavaScript function outside the Vue-instance? 
And if so, - how would that look? And can I call it from inside my Vue-instace?

---

**What I've tried**

- [vue-gtag](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/). Implements the Google Universal Tracking code and not GTM. This is close to what I was hoping for, though.
- [vue-gtm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gtm). Requires Vue-Router.
- [vue-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-analytics). Same argument as `vue-gtag`, except for Google Analytics and not Google Universal Tracking.
- [vue-head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head). Requires Vue-Router.

---

**Extra info**

For others using this: you can see the [getCookie and setCookie JavaScript functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103596/1766219).